# Write Data in Google Spreadsheet using submitButton from Ui Service

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im trying to do a script in GAS to write data from a form that i create using Ui Service, but it does not work.

The form shows ok, but the function that saves the data in the spreadsheet does not work:

```
function SalvaRegistro(e) {
var app=UiApp.getActiveApplication();
var DataValue=e.parameter.Data;
var TicketIDValue=e.value.TicketID;
var TicketTypeValue=e.value.TicketType;
var DemandedByValue=e.value.DemandedBy;
var AnalystValue=e.value.Analyst;
var StatusValue=e.value.Status;
var DescriptionValue=e.value.Description;
var TicketIDValue=e.value.TicketID;

sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Data")).setValue(DataValue);
sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Ticket ID")).setValue(TicketIDValue);
sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Ticket Type")).setValue(TicketTypeValue);
sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Demandado por")).setValue(DemandedByValue);
sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Analista")).setValue(AnalystValue);
sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Status")).setValue(StatusValue);
sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Descrição")).setValue(DescriptionValue);
return app.close()
                  }
```

How can i make the form write the data in the spreadsheet?

Comment: What value comes in the sheet ? Is it 'undefined' or really nothing happens? Have you an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a FormPanel and a Submit button inside the GUI you can simply use a predefined function called doPost(e) where e var will contain all the FormPanel values.
For each input field also set the Name parameter in the GUI Builder so you can reference them by name. Here is the code:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var txt1 = e.parameter.TextBox1Name;
  var txt2 = e.parameter.TextBox2Name;
  ss.getActiveSheet().appendRow([txt1,txt2]);
}
```

For what I can see from your code you just need to append a row so instead of looking at the last row you can simply use the appendRow function as I did.

Comment: One point: the Data (the date) was coming with a value undefined because i used the setEnabled(false) it the textBox. I changed it to setReadOnly(true) and the problem is gone. But now, using the debug tool in the script editor, comes an error saying that is not possible to read the property "parameter" of undefined.
The strange is that the date value is included in their respective cell.